# How do I use Typescript path aliases in Vite?

Tags: typescript, vite

How do I set up and use typescript path aliases like `@/shared/types` in a Vite project? I'm getting this error: `Failed to resolve import "@/shared/types"`

Here's a part of my `tsconfig.json`:

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a plugin for that: `vite-tsconfig-paths`. You run

```
npm install --save-dev vite-tsconfig-paths
```

and import it in your `vite.config`:

```
// ...
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths

Answer (score 9):

You need to configure both `vite.config.ts` and `tsconfig.json` files. Your `tsconfig.json` looks correct, but inside the `vite.config.ts` file you need to import the `path` module and map the path aliases to absolute paths using something like `path.resolve()`. And make sure to remove any asterisk characters (*)!

For example, if your `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "../",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@server/*": ["./server/src/*"]
    },
  }
```

Then this is how you should configure `vite.config.ts`:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
      "@server": path.resolve(__dirname, "../server/src"),
    },
  },
  plugins: [react()],
});
```

You may need to import react from `'@vitejs/plugin-react'`, depending on which options you chose when creating your app.