# How do I use Vite path aliases in tsconfig?

Tags: typescript, vite, tsconfig, tsconfig-paths, tsconfig.json

> **Ref:** [How do I use Typescript path aliases in Vite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77249074/how-do-i-use-typescript-path-aliases-in-vite)

I know a plugin [vite-tsconfig-paths](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-tsconfig-paths). However, this plugin will use the path aliases configs in **tsconfig.json**, then let vite config also use it.

I want to **reverse** it. Just config path aliases in **vite.config.ts**, then tsconfig will use vite path aliases config. Because we can do some things functionally in vite.config.ts, but tsconfig.json just a **JSON**.

The principle is to extract path aliases info from vite.config.ts, then generate a tsconfig.paths.json. We can use "extends" in project tsconfig.json to use it.

Is there some packages that can do it?

Comment: So you can just programmatically change `tsconfig.json` and use `vite-tsconfig-paths`?