How do I solve the error "Failed to resolve import "src/lib/utils" from ... Does the file exist?"
I am a beginner in react and am trying to follow this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_W3R2VwRyF4) on youtube. I am trying to test out the button component I am building, but I keep getting an error message:
"[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "src/lib/utils" from "src/components/ui/button.tsx". Does the file exist?"
For reference, I am using vite + react + tailwind.
I have attached a screen shot with the rest of the error message.
This is the code button.tsx:
import * as React from "react"
import { Slot } from "@radix-ui/react-slot"
import { cva, type VariantProps } from "class-variance-authority"

import { cn } from "src/lib/utils"

This is the code in utils.ts:
import { type ClassValue, clsx } from "clsx"
import { twMerge } from "tailwind-merge"

export function cn(...inputs: ClassValue[]) {
  return twMerge(clsx(inputs))
}


I am importing the button component from @/components/ui/button to SignupForm.tsx with this command:
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"

I deleted "@", but when I remove it from the path "@/components/ui/button", I get the error: "Cannot find module 'components/ui/button' or its corresponding type declarations."
I am assuming that it is a syntax OR a path error I am overlooking. Does anyone have any thoughts? Thank you.

Try "./src/lib/utils" (with the ./ at the start).

@/ here is a path alias, make sure to configure TypeScript and Vite to resolve the pathes:
If you'r using TypeScript update tsconfig.json to add:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    }
    // ...
  }
}

And vite.config.ts:
import path from "path"
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
})

You'll also need to install @types/node to type path:
npm i -D @types/node

Then whenever you import something from @/path/to/whatever the compiler will resolve it to ./src/path/to/whatever.

I deleted "@", but when I remove it from the path "@/components/ui/button", I get the error: "Cannot find module 'components/ui/button' or its corresponding type declarations."

Make sure to revert this change, or to run again:
npx shadcn-ui init
npx shadcn-ui add button


I tried doing this and still got the same error.

Can you share a repo or Sandbox?

Here is the link to my github repo: https://github.com/tmhourani/snapgram

Move utils.ts file to lib and remove @ directory or run the commands at the end of the answer again

I moved utils.ts file to lib and removed the @ directory, and now I am getting the error in localhost:5173: "[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "src/lib/utils" from "src/components/ui/button.tsx". Does the file exist?"

I went into my SignupForm.tsx file and changed the import statement from "@/components/ui/button" to "src/components/ui/button", and I am getting this error now: "[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "src/components/ui/button" from "src/_auth/forms/SignupForm.tsx". Does the file exist?"

See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/77249092/18079514

I did everything and resolved the issue, but my button component is not showing up on my UI.

Create a new question explaining what's going on

Here is the link to my new question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78572199/button-component-not-showing-up-on-react-js-website

Well what i did is to change the @ instances to src

vite.config.ts

import path from "path";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      src: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});


tsconfig.app.json

"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "src/*": ["./src/*"]
},


Exact this answer worked for me!
