button component not showing up on react.js website
I am following a YouTube tutorial and trying to build and render a button component on my website using shadcn + tailwind + react and it is not showing up.
Previously, I had some issues with paths, and after deleting the @ folder and running the npm install --save-dev vite-tsconfig-paths command and importing it into my vite.config:
// ...
import tsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [tsconfigPaths()],
});

I solved the first path issue.
Now, I am dealing with a UI issue in which the button component I am trying to implement is not showing up on my website. The only code I have altered are those above and adding onto the AuthLayout.tsx file in my project:
import { Outlet , Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const AuthLayout = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = false; 
  return (
    <>
     {isAuthenticated ? (
      <Navigate to= "/" />
     ): (
      <>

        <section className= "flex flex-1 justify-center items-center flex-col py-10">
          <Outlet/>
        </section>
      </>
     )}
    </>
  )
}

export default AuthLayout

Here is my button.tsx file:
import * as React from "react"
import { Slot } from "@radix-ui/react-slot"
import { cva, type VariantProps } from "class-variance-authority"

import { cn } from "src/lib/utils"

const buttonVariants = cva(
  "inline-flex items-center justify-center whitespace-nowrap rounded-md text-sm font-medium ring-offset-background transition-colors focus-visible:outline-none focus-visible:ring-2 focus-visible:ring-ring focus-visible:ring-offset-2 disabled:pointer-events-none disabled:opacity-50",
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        default: "bg-primary text-primary-foreground hover:bg-primary/90",
        destructive:
          "bg-destructive text-destructive-foreground hover:bg-destructive/90",
        outline:
          "border border-input bg-background hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground",
        secondary:
          "bg-secondary text-secondary-foreground hover:bg-secondary/80",
        ghost: "hover:bg-accent hover:text-accent-foreground",
        link: "text-primary underline-offset-4 hover:underline",
      },
      size: {
        default: "h-10 px-4 py-2",
        sm: "h-9 rounded-md px-3",
        lg: "h-11 rounded-md px-8",
        icon: "h-10 w-10",
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: "default",
      size: "default",
    },
  }
)

export interface ButtonProps
  extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>,
    VariantProps<typeof buttonVariants> {
  asChild?: boolean
}

const Button = React.forwardRef<HTMLButtonElement, ButtonProps>(
  ({ className, variant, size, asChild = false, ...props }, ref) => {
    const Comp = asChild ? Slot : "button"
    return (
      <Comp
        className={cn(buttonVariants({ variant, size, className }))}
        ref={ref}
        {...props}
      />
    )
  }
)
Button.displayName = "Button"

export { Button, buttonVariants }

Here is where I am trying to render the button in SignupForm.tsx:
import { Button } from "src/components/ui/button"

const SignupForm = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button>Click me</Button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default SignupForm
I have been following the tutorial step-by-step, so I imagine that there is still some path issue I am not noticing. Github repo with all of the files updated

please update the question to include where you render the button

@AhmedAbdelbaset Updated, and I am rendering the button on a website application.

Your code doesn't include  anywhere.

@Phix in my SignupForm.tsx file (github link: https://github.com/tmhourani/snapgram/blob/main/src/auth/forms/SignupForm.tsx) I have included .

Please post code here and not offsite.

@Phix I edited the post and added SignupForm.tsx contents.

And you're sure the sign up form is being rendered?

@Phix I believe so. How can I know for sure? I am a beginner.

@houra-dev I suggest you take a few steps back to learn react. If you're not sure what route you're on, introducing extra libraries that may cause unknown issues is going to be a headache. You can know by rendering a simple span with text like "you're on the sign up form" to make sure everything's working on the text side and not an issue with shad

I run this problem and solve it
here is the step:
1st: All my working dir has src folder so inside add a folder name: utils
2nd: Delete the components.json files
and run the npx shadcn@latest init
it will reinstall the npx and add the utils the files and It will fix
